# How to send web socket connection to different process in tornado?

Tags: sockets, multiprocessing, tornado, python-3.6, pickle

I am using tornado to implement the server with web sockets. I have some multi core CPU and I want to use the other CPU as well. So I though of using python `multiprocess` module. I want to accept the connection on the main process and send the data using other process. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to share the socket information between processes?
2. Is it better to use `pickling` or is there any other method that I can use?
3. If I use `pickling` the additional duplicates file descriptors that are created by it will affect the number of file descriptors the OS can handle or is it the same file descriptor shared between the processes?

**Explanation:**
There will be a lot of incoming connections and there will be a lot of messages from the client side so I do not want to the main event to loop to be stuck in sending the data. That is why I am trying to use different process to send the data to the connections.

**Output of strace**
I have started `strace` and given the process id from which I am sending data to web sockets. The output of `strace` looks like this:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 91.01    0.019570           0    441736           sendto
  3.60    0.000774           0     29314           read
  3.14    0.000675           0     30623           clock_gettime
  1.15    0.000248           0      2909           write
  0.96    0.000206           0     11855           epoll_wait
  0.13    0.000029           0      1534       680 recvfrom
  0.00    0.000000           0        17           open
  0.00    0.000000           0        34           close
  0.00    0.000000           0        17           stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        17           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        34           poll
  0.00    0.000000           0        39           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        26           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0       408           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0       134           ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0        34           socket
  0.00    0.000000           0        34        17 connect
  0.00    0.000000           0       300           setsockopt
  0.00    0.000000           0        17           getsockopt
  0.00    0.000000           0       200           fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0        17           gettimeofday
  0.00    0.000000           0      1185           epoll_ctl
  0.00    0.000000           0       178        78 accept4
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.021502                520662       775 total
```

Is there any reason that i am getting error `recvfrom` and `connect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Tornado does not support this. There are techniques like `SCM_RIGHTS` to transfer file descriptors to other processes, but this will give you a raw socket in the other process, not a Tornado websocket object (and there is no supported way to construct a websocket object for this socket).

The recommended approach with Tornado is to run one process per CPU and let them share traffic by either putting them behind a load balancer or using SO_REUSEPORT. Sending the data in Tornado is non-blocking; you must make sure that your own code is non-blocking too (using asynchronous interfaces or thread pools).

Comment: I have a situation where I have to receive UDP data on the network socket and when there are too many connections on the server the UDP will start dropping the packets. That is the reason I want to transfer the connection to different process. I just have to send to the sockets from other process. So when I receive the raw sockets to send the data is it like normal socket send or is there any different protocol that we need to follow for  web sockets?

Comment: UDP is different and I don't have as much experience with it. But any process can receive UDP packets on the port and I don't think there's any "socket information" to share between processes.

Comment: let me explain a little more about this. I am receiving UDP packets and that  is not by the client connections. The clients will be connected using normal web sockets. UDP receive will be from one of my servers which will have the actual data that has to be sent to users through web sockets.

Comment: Got it. So in that case you're not sharing the sockets per se, you're just relaying the UDP data from the process that received it to the others. There are a lot of ways to do this. One way would be to create a multiprocessing.Queue for each worker process before forking.

Comment: I have created a pipe to communicate between the processes and added the file descriptor to tornado io loop.

Comment: I am using web sockets to communicate with clients. Is `write_message` eg `conn.write_message("some Message") ` blocking? will this take any CPU to write into the file descriptors ?

Comment: Everything takes at least a little bit of CPU. `write_message` uses a little CPU time including the `write(2)` system call (unless the outgoing IOStream buffer is full), but it doesn't wait for the data to actually be sent on the network.

Comment: I am connecting 100 clients and sending the data for every 1 second to them that is like 1 send per client per second. But the CPU is reaching 50%. The machine that I am running this test is `AWS m4.large EC2` with `2vCPU` and `8GiB` of memory. If I test this setup without `write_message` everything is working good and when I add the `write_message` the load on the CPU  is increasing. So could it be the blocking call that I may have?

Comment: The output of `strace` has been added.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer to the 1st question:

`is it possible to share the socket information between processes?`

May depend on OS, but with Linux it is possible at least 2 ways:

- When the main process accepts a new TCP connection, it can fork a new child process for handling it. After fork, the new child process will have the same socket file descriptor than the main process.
- Use a UNIX domain socket to pass file descriptor of a socket from the main process to the other process. This requires to use of SCM_RIGHTS control message and ancillary data. Check [this](https://sumitomohiko.wordpress.com/2015/09/24/file-descriptor-passing-with-sendmsg2-and-recvmsg2-over-unix-domain-socket/).

Comment: I am using Linux. The socket connections will change dynamically and I have to add or remove those connection from both parent and child process. So from what I know if I fork the processes only initial connection will be shared. So I have to look into Unix domain sockets?

Comment: @aja Link to related topic added to the answer.